# JavaScript - trouble accessing DOM of dynamically generated local iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, dynamically-generated

I'm having trouble accessing the DOM of an iframe content document **if** I create the iframe dynamically in JavaScript rather than hard-coding it in the HTML.

I'm finding this so far testing in Mac FF26 and Safari 6. It is a local iframe document on the desktop, so there should be no cross-domain issues.

The iframe I generate appears normally in the browser window. But trying to access it with contentDocument, the body element seems to be empty.

Is this a known issue? Perhaps I'm generating my iframe in an unusual way:

```
var newIframe = document.createElement("iframe");
newIframe.id = "generatedIframe";
newIframe.src = "test.html";
document.body.appendChild(newIframe);
var iframeTag = document.getElementById("generatedIframe");


// the iframe will be appearing normally in the browser now


// but this fails -- innerHTML is empty string:

var iframeContent = iframeTag.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML;

// same reference code works if the iframe is hard-coded in HTML instead
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact your problem is not the way you generated your iframe.

The iframe DOM is only available after it has been loaded.

The code behind illustrates what I mean :

In your parent window container :

```
<script>
    function doSomething() { alert(iframeTag.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML()); }
</script>
```

In your iframe document

```
<body onload="window.parent.doSomething();"></body>
```

Comment: Thank you -- that's exactly what's happening. Problem solved.

Comment: I checked "solved" but I can't vote this up as I have "no reputation". I suppose that's better than a bad one.